# Rails App hangs after few requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, freeze, bitnami

I have Bitnami Rails stack installed on my Mac. To better explain my problem i created a simple scaffold based rails app with mysql as the backend. I can get to perform simple POST and GET requests for a while and after a few requests the app just hangs indefinitely. No exception caught or anything worthwhile in the development log to report this strange behavior. This is the last bit from the development log before the app froze:

```
Processing WritedatasController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-30 20:38:51) [GET]
   [4;36;1mWritedata Load (0.7ms) [0m    [0;1mSELECT * FROM `writedatas`  [0m
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering writedatas/index
   [4;35;1mWritedata Columns (2.9ms) [0m    [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `writedatas` [0m
Completed in 99ms (View: 88, DB: 4) | 200 OK [http://localhost/writedatas]
   [4;36;1mSQL (0.2ms) [0m    [0;1mSET NAMES 'utf8' [0m
   [4;35;1mSQL (0.1ms) [0m    [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0 [0m


Processing WritedatasController#new (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-30 20:38:52) [GET]
   [4;36;1mWritedata Columns (2.0ms) [0m    [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `writedatas` [0m
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering writedatas/new
Rendered writedatas/_form (5.9ms)
Completed in 34ms (View: 25, DB: 2) | 200 OK [http://localhost/writedatas/new]
   [4;36;1mSQL (0.4ms) [0m    [0;1mSET NAMES 'utf8' [0m
   [4;35;1mSQL (0.1ms) [0m    [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0 [0m


Processing WritedatasController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-30 20:39:17) [GET]
   [4;36;1mWritedata Load (0.7ms) [0m    [0;1mSELECT * FROM `writedatas`  [0m
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering writedatas/index
   [4;35;1mWritedata Columns (2.6ms) [0m    [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `writedatas` [0m
Completed in 101ms (View: 90, DB: 4) | 200 OK [http://localhost/writedatas]
```

It just hung at this point. And after this happens i have to restart the server, for it to hang again after few requests. This is the weirdest problem i have faced and i am truly stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide enough for us to comment.
Run the server in debugger mode and try to pinpoint the problem by stepping through the code.

If there's nothing wrong with the code, try running it with a clean set of data.

Comment: Ran the server in debugging mode. The request returns a 302 Found. I did run it with a clean set of data. As i said its a new app with a simple scaffold. I can add records using the console without any problems thou.

Comment: I'm assuming its not the application. Could you try running it on something other than apache like mongrel?